# How to create user registration form by inserting default siloutte image based on selected gender with Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create gender-based registration form with Laravel.
If a user selects a male gender, the male siloutte image is inserted into database otherwise the female image will be inserted.

I tried this for couple of days but only male image is inserted.

Below is the source codes:

1. RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data){

    $gender = array("Male", "Female");

    if('gender' == $gender[0]){
       return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'profile_image' => $data['profile_male_image']
       ]);
   }else{
       return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'phone' => $data['phone'],
        'gender' => $data['gender'],
        'profile_image' => $data['profile_female_image']
   ]);
  }
}
```

2. Register.blade.php

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    @csrf

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="first_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('first_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="first_name" placeholder="First name" required autofocus>

                            @error('first_name')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="last_name" type="text" class="form-control @error('last_name') is-invalid @enderror" name="last_name" placeholder="Last name" required autofocus>

                            @error('last_name')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" placeholder="Email address" required autocomplete="email">

                            @error('email')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off">

                            @error('password')
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" placeholder="Confirm password" required autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <input id="phone" type="text" class="form-control @error('phone') is-invalid @enderror" name="phone" placeholder="Phone number" required autofocus>

                            @error('phone')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <select id="gender" class="form-control @error('gender') is-invalid @enderror" name="gender" required>
                                <option value="" selected="selected">Please select gender</option>
                                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                            </select>
                            @error('gender')
                            <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @enderror
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="profile_male_image" value="images/users/male.jpg">
                    <input type="hidden" name="profile_female_image" value="images/users/female.jpg">
                    <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
                                {{ __('Register') }}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

Thanks for you input.

Comment: try `if($data['gender'] == $gender[0]){` instead of `if('gender' == $gender[0]){`

Comment: Thanks @iamab. It's working now.